# XCODE 6.1.1 Framework issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, frameworks, xcode6

I have built a cocoa framework via XCode 6.1.1, also created a universal version of the framework, then when I import the framework into a project, an compiling error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_UIResponder", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_AppDelegate in AppDelegate.o
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_UIResponder", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_AppDelegate in AppDelegate.o
  "_UIApplicationMain", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_UIViewController", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_ViewController in ViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_UIViewController", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_ViewController in ViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Wonder to know why?
And how to analyse the cause of the problem?

Comment: Is your AppDelegate in Objective-C++ (.mm file) by any chance?I just had this issue and adding the UIKit.framework for linking resolves that problem.. I am still searching for an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the armv7 architecture to your framework before building it.
Because the project where you use the framework in has this architecture.

You also can check the path to the framework (framework search-path)

Comment: The framework has armv7 architeture build already. checked several times